# Which rules should use CFLAGS in GNU make

Tags: c, makefile, cflags

In my makefile for a C project, I have set the CFLAGS variable as follows -

```
CFLAGS=-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O2 -isystem $(SQLITEDIR)
```

I expected this variable to be used in the rule for building object files since the flags affect the compilation step

However, in the GNU make manual

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Implicit

I see the following example -

```
foo : foo.o bar.o
    cc -o foo foo.o bar.o $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I think this is a rule for the linking step so I understand it why it include LDFLAGS, but what is the purpose CFLAGS here?

Comment: Where's the `-g` flag set?  Why isn't it set?  If it's in `${CFLAGS}`, you need `${CFLAGS}` in the linking command options as well as the compiling command options.  Using `${CFLAGS}` in both protects you from subtle (and not so subtle) misuses of flags, at minimal cost.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, good point, I have added -g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(I am guessing that you are using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) on some Linux system)</sup>

You are right in your use of `CFLAGS` (but I would add `-g` there). But I am not sure you need `-isystem $(SQLITEDIR)`, it probably can be `-I $(SQLITEDIR)` instead. The `-isystem` [directory option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) to GCC is rarely useful.

Read first the documentation about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), assuming you are using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. BTW, you could have `CC= gcc` in your `Makefile`. If your compiler is not GCC but something else (e.g. [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) read its documentation.

Then, run `make -p` to understand the builtin rules of your [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (there are many of them). You'll find out that many builtin rules are using `CFLAGS` etc. And that is why it is simpler to have a `CFLAGS` variable in your `Makefile`; if possible, take advantage of some builtin rules known to `make`.

BTW, you could avoid using any builtin rules and variables, but that is poor taste.

The POSIX standard defines some options understood by `cc` and by `make` (and some minimal rules for `make`). Both GCC and GNU make have much more. Read [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

`CFLAGS` usually contain some (optimization or other) flags (e.g. `-O` or `-g`, or `-pthread`) which are also relevant at the [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) step (assuming you link with `gcc`, which will invoke `ld`). That is why you usually link using `gcc` (as `$(CC)` in your recipe) with both `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`.

You could use `make --trace` or even [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (as `remake -x`) to debug your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

Comment: It might be nice to explain why `-isystem` is "rarely useful." :-)  Using `-isystem` is nice if you intend to error on warnings and you're including third-party headers.

Comment: BUT AFAIK `-isystem` is really GCC specific. POSIX knows about `-I` but probably not about `-isystem` (and many compilers understand `-I`). I never used `-isystem` myself.

Comment: Yes, I am using GNU make and gcc on Linux. I used -isystem $(SQLITEDIR) instead of -I $(SQLITEDIR) to avoid seeing compiler warnings concerning the sqlite library in $(SQLITEDIR).  I am using CC=gcc in my makefile. Now I understand some flags are relevant to both compilation and linking. Thanks

Comment: While `isystem` might not be in POSIX, but it is supported by GCC, Clang, ICC. Disregarding it just because it's not in the standard is a bit short-sighted. It's one of the most useful options, because generally you do want to enable a `-Werror` in CI for your project, but what you gonna do about warnings coming from third-party libraries you have no control over? Even fixing them upstream wouldn't help for older versions of libraries. And the answer is: include their headers with `-isystem` to suppress any warnings coming from them.